# I am looking for a method with Arrayformula and vlookup to find the first non empty cell from the bottom up

Tags: google-sheets

I have found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/an-arrayformula-to-find-the-previous-non-empty-cell-in-another-column) the following wonderful formula for Sheets to find the first non empty cell in a column using arrayformula and vlookup.

`=ArrayFormula(vlookup(ROW(1:10),{IF(LEN(A1:A10)>0,ROW(1:10),""),A1:A10},2))`

My question is whether is it possible to achieve the same but from the bottom up.

I have created [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJB4ZBIrdAEImNTpaJ0dcG5d1tORUGY6IQWQYW68AZg/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet where values in red in the second tab are the expected results to get with the formula.

The results of this formula are

```
aa
 a
vv
 v
 v
cc
 c
```

And what I'm looking for is:

```
vv
 c
 c
 c
cc
 b
 b
bb
 a
aa
```

Comment: Can you put in your question what the values are that the formula is acting on to get the results you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use a formula similar to what you have already, but use the `SORT` function to flip your input range upside-down.*

#### Formula:

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(1:16),{IF(LEN(SORT(A1:A16,ROW(A1:A16),0))>0,ROW(1:16),""),SORT(A1:A16,ROW(A1:A16),0)},2)),ROW(A1:A16),0)
```

Will yeild the following result if used in cell `B1` on data `A1:A16`:

```
    A    |    B
===================
       1 |       1
---------+---------
         |       3
---------+---------
       3 |       3
---------+---------
         |       4
---------+---------
       4 |       4
---------+---------
 asaffas | asaffas
---------+---------
         |      sd 
---------+---------
      sd |      sd
---------+---------
         |    fefe
---------+---------
         |    fefe
---------+---------
         |    fefe
---------+---------
    fefe |    fefe
---------+---------
         |    1000
---------+---------
         |    1000
---------+---------
         |    1000
---------+---------
   1000  |    1000
---------+---------
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- Takes the values in `A1:A16` and sorts them from bottom to top
- Creates a range which contains a row number if the corresponding cell in this sorted array has data, and `""` if the cell is blank
- Creates an array of two ranges: the first is the range in the previous step, and the second is the sorted cells
- Uses `VLOOKUP` to search this new array for blank cells, and returns the corresponding value in the sorted range if the cell is blank
- Sorts the return range again to flip it back the correct way

#### Things to note:

- The range can only be one column
- If the range specified has empty cells at the bottom, then all cells below the bottom-most cell will display `#N/A`

  - (For example, if you specify the range `A1:A18` but in column A the last cell to have data is `A16`, then `B17` and `B18` will display `#N/A`.

#### References:

- [SORT - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ROW - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)
- [IF function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [LEN - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en)

#### Releated Questions:

- [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/an-arrayformula-to-find-the-previous-non-empty-cell-in-another-column)

Answer (score 0):

#### Generic Solution:

Generic way to get the row number of the first non-empty cell, from the bottom up in a range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROWS(A1:A10)-MIN(IF(SORT(A1:A10,ROW(A1:A10),0)<>"",ROW(A1:A10)))+1)
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- Sorts the range `A1:A10` from bottom to top based on its respective row number
- Finds the minimum row number of this range which has content in it
- Subtracts this number from the total number of rows in this range
- Adds one to correct 0-indexing

#### References:

- [ARRAYFORMULA - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [ROWS - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en)
- [MIN - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en)
- [IF function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [SORT - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [ROW - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)

Comment: Hmm...I have tried it, but it doesn't seem to work for me. it just gives me a number in the cell where the formula has been pasted...

Comment: That's exactly what it does - it "find the first non empty cell from the bottom up". If you give me an example set of data, or a sanitised sheet, then I may be able to help you further

Comment: sure! I have created this sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJB4ZBIrdAEImNTpaJ0dcG5d1tORUGY6IQWQYW68AZg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: in the first tab, there's the formula and in the second tab is in red the results i would like to get. thanks

Comment: I provided a second answer to cover your specific case, but I have kept this one up as it is more generic to the question in the title which may be helpful for future internet travellers